# Como ativar editor de link de uma post type criado?

Tags: wordpress

Tenho uma post type criada, mas não mostra o editor de url da pagina criada, alguém poderia dizer onde eu declaro que no post type terá um campo para editar a url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagino que vc esteja falando do editor de permalinks como esse?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se sim, ele depende da opção "title" estar presente no array `supports` quando você cria o Post Type:

ex.:

```
<?php
     $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            /* todas as outras opções */ 
            'supports' => array(
                'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail' 
            ),
        );

        register_post_type( 'slug', $args );
```